# Row-wise difference in two list using Data.Table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I want to use `data.table` to incrementally find out new elements i.e. for every row, I'd see whether values in list have been seen before. If they are, we will ignore them. If not, we will select them.

I was able to wrap elements by group in a list, but I am unsure how I can find incremental differences.

Here's my attempt:

```
       df = data.table::data.table(id = c('A','B','C','A','B','A','A','A','D','E','E','E'), 
Value = c(1,2,3,4,3,5,2,3,7,2,3,9))

       df_wrapped=df[,.(Values=(list(unique(Value)))), by=id]

       expected_output = data.table::data.table(id = c("A","B","C","D","E"),
Value = list(c(1,4,5,2,3),c(2,3),c(3),c(7),c(2,3,9)),
Diff=list(c(1,4,5,2,3),c(NA),c(NA),c(7),c(9)),
Count = c(5,0,0,1,1))
```

Thoughts about expected output:

- For the first row, all elements are unique. So, we will include them in `Diff` column.
- In the second row, `2,3` have occurred in row 1. So, we will ignore them. Ditto for row 3.
- Similarly, `7` and `9` are seen for the first time in row 4 and 5, so we will include them.

Here's visual representation:

```
expected_output
   id     Value      Diff Count
    A 1,4,5,2,3 1,4,5,2,3     5
    B       2,3        NA     0
    C         3        NA     0
    D         7         7     1
    E     2,3,9         9     1
```

I'd appreciate any thoughts. I am only looking for `data.table` based solutions because of performance issues in my original dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why you specifically need to put them in a list, but otherwise I wrote a small piece that could help you.

```
df = data.table::data.table(id = c('A','B','C','A','B','A','A','A','D','E','E','E'), 
                            Value = c(1,2,3,4,3,5,2,3,7,2,3,9))

df = df[order(id, Value)]
df = df[duplicated(Value) == FALSE, diff := Value][]
df = df[, count := uniqueN(diff, na.rm = TRUE), by = id]
```

The outcome would be:

```
> df
    id Value diff count
 1:  A     1    1     5
 2:  A     2    2     5
 3:  A     3    3     5
 4:  A     4    4     5
 5:  A     5    5     5
 6:  B     2   NA     0
 7:  B     3   NA     0
 8:  C     3   NA     0
 9:  D     7    7     1
10:  E     2   NA     1
11:  E     3   NA     1
12:  E     9    9     1
```

Hope this helps, or at least get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another possible approach:

```
library(data.table)
df = data.table(
    id = c('A','B','C','A','B','A','A','A','D','E','E','E'), 
    Value = c(1,2,3,4,3,5,2,3,7,2,3,9))

valset <- c()
df[, {
        d <- setdiff(Value, valset)
        valset <- unique(c(valset, Value))
        .(Values=.(Value), Diff=.(d), Count=length(d))
    }, 
    by=.(id)]
```

output:

```
   id    Values      Diff Count
1:  A 1,4,5,2,3 1,4,5,2,3     5
2:  B       2,3               0
3:  C         3               0
4:  D         7         7     1
5:  E     2,3,9         9     1
```

Comment: Thanks chinsoon12. Could you please explain the usage (and meaning) of `.` and `{}` in your solution. I am seeing so many `.` in `data.table` for the first time in my life. I have never understood `.` to be honest. Hope you understand.

Comment: The expression `.()` is a shorthand alias to `list()` (see `j` argument in `?data.table`). `{}` is just the usual braces to enclose expressions.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am curious: why is there no difference between `by = .(id)` (your code) and `by = id`? Thanks in advance. I didn't know that we can have expressions in `data.table`. Do you know any material I can read on this topic? Thanks again.

Comment: you can start with the data.table documentation and vignettes.